# How to add font to windows and Linux system

Tags: linux, windows, pdf

Hey I want to translate pdf file.

My problem is that the data I read is a language the isn't supported by all fonts, so when the font is something like Times New Roman-13299 I get ""09/2023 tlli1n7 l:ltll tll17n \n02/ I 0/2023 l'lKn::l o::m, \nI 7w;i I '11 \n".

For example:

copying "סה"כ תשלומים" with David font and paste result: íéîåìùú ë"äñ

copying with font Times New Roman successed

copying with Times New Roman-13299 and paste result: tlli1n7 l:ltll tll17n

I think that my windows/Linux cant recognize this font and that is the problem, how I add something like Times New Roman-13299 to my system?

Pdf File exampe copy paste each row and see the ouput:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ESj7uLeXdKPnXerzJaXhdR9C8Qkl85YX/view?usp=sharing

Comment: *so when the font is something like Times New Roman-13299 I get...* So what was it *meant* to be?

Comment: I added example @g00se

Comment: @KJ I added example I hope its clear enough, you can see the font when you edit the file

Comment: @KJ I want to translate pdf The solution I think about is to use OCR AI of google/azure and make template then extract the data and put it, but it would be a lot easier if I could just search and replace on the same pdf

Comment: If some one used the font to write the right information there isn't a way to use the same font he did to read it right?

Comment: rtl or ltr isn't the problem, i can use David font with hebrew and english the same way and transform between supported fonts and the info will be the same, what you mean by scanner? I don't think the company that create this pdf create also the used font.

Comment: "Brother Scanner System : MFC-L6900DW series" created it

Comment: Well If I cant get the same decoding of the used font and then read the file as binary and use the same algorithm I don't think there is a solution. its just I don't understand how the pdf show me the right data and the moment I edit it its destroyed, like the info isn't signed to the used font and its just drawing on canvas. I have the same problem with other files and other font so its not unique case

Comment: Complex stuff, and all new to me, but I suspect the answer might [lie here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23104/using-and-interpreting-pdffonts)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately from a programming perspective, the file is not a good candidate for correction. In some cases we can use programmable recoding to correct for poor mapping of characters. However, in this case it will be easier to re-print and then rescan with Right to Left Hebrew trained OCR.

A scanner with OCR has used similar Latin characters (e.g. 1) repeatedly, to be used as replacements for the Hebrew characters. There is a fairly slim possibility to use visual remapping to attempt some remediation, as seen below. However from experience is will be a slow human based task unless you accept a high percent of failures using a programable method.

Here each of the `tll` = `ש` character groups are a different shape before scanning. That means each ש is a different character group, making them hard to count as 3 numeric copies of one single character. However many are simply coded as Latin numeral `1` (see the second remap image below).

[image]

Auto correct will entrench the bad Latin characters even more so. Even the zer0 has been badly detected as Latin capital `O`. There are cases where one Hebrew character is now 2 or 3 or more Latin characters, and others where one latin character represents multiple Hebrew characters.

[image]

I attempted to try mapping some 1 into Hebrew matching the scans but there are just so many and frustratingly 2 Hebrew blobs of ink simply allocated a single Latin 1. So no programmer is likely to cope with ALL the errors within a short simple program. It would be faster to retype the whole
document, in Hebrew

[image]

### Answer

You need to start the OCR again with **Hebrew** as the Primary Language, but beware most western OCR will try to reverse pages with mixed Latin and Hebrew words like this.

[image]

Comment: Ty for your answer, ya I agree with you I will use OCR now I think if there is a way to copy template and insert the scanned data with OCR or I must create the template(boxes,  borders, tables) with hard coded x,y games